# How do I run an application with arguments from the command line without losing the terminal?

Tags: command-line

I use dwm as a window manager on Ubuntu, I like tiled windows and I like them as few as possible. I sometimes need to run an application (let's say it's the pdf viewer mupdf in x11) from the terminal, the application will be launched in a new window but the terminal from which I launched becomes this prompt-less console for that application to log whatever.

I use dmenu to launch applications, but sometimes an application needs arguments (file names) to start. I use uxrvt within x11 managed by dwm.