# Use Terminal after opening process

Tags: command-line

I am new to Linux and using Terminal. If I open an application within terminal, I noticed that it renders my terminal session to be unusable and I can't enter any more commands.The Terminal session is focused on the task of running the application only. Is there a way to bypass this or do I just have to wait until I end my session with the process.

Comment: ...And a bunch of others

Comment: @JacobVlijm: What is the "canonical" answer to this question, to which all dupes should refer?

Comment: @krlmlr It is one of these subjects that pass by on a regular base (in different variants). I already mentioned http://askubuntu.com/questions/106351/running-programs-in-the-background-from-terminal. A quick search also gives http://askubuntu.com/questions/319843/i-cant-use-the-terminal-while-gedit-command-is-running, http://askubuntu.com/questions/331451/how-do-i-run-an-application-with-arguments-from-the-command-line-without-losing. I also remember an extensive answer on the subject by KasiyA (couldn't find it in a quick search). Looking on StackOverflow, there are many more on the subject.

Answer (score 8):

Use `disown` command:

```
gedit & disown
```

This way launched process is disconnected from the terminal it was launched in.

Comment: Is that tha same as `nohup gedit &` or is there some difference?

Comment: Effect is similar, but when `nohup` is used, one wouldn't be able to send `SIGHUP` signal (e.g. using `kill` command) to the process. Note, however, that process may change it's behavior regarding signals itself.

From `man nohup`: "`nohup` - run a command immune to hangups ...".
From `man bash`: "Before exiting, an interactive shell resends  the `SIGHUP` to  all  jobs [...] To prevent the shell from sending the signal to a particular job, it should be removed from the jobs table with the `disown` builtin or marked to not receive `SIGHUP` using `disown -h`."

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways that you can continue working.

If you opened a gnome-terminal via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> you can choose File from the top menu bar and then choose to open a new tab or a new terminal window via the menu or with the shortcut keys with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> or SHIFT-CTRL-N respectively(while gnome-terminal has focus).

If you've opened a terminal session with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>, you can switch to another with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> through <kbd>F6</kbd>.

Another option is to background the task as you launch it by placing an & at the end of the command for example `dd if=infile of=outfile &`. you can string commands by putting a double ampersand between them. `ls /home > dir.file && du /home/Downloads` for example.

Of course placing processes in the background requires a way of handling background tasks. the `fg PID` command allows you to bring a process to the foreground. you can obtain the PID with the `jobs` command more information on handling background tasks can be found [here](https://kb.iu.edu/d/afnz)

you can also use nohup and disown as mentioned in the other good answers here. Differences between these approaches are discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and)

Comment: Note that to background a command, you need to add a single ampersand (`&`) to the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

`nohup command &` will do the trick.  You will get just one message in terminal , hit  <kbd>Enter</kbd>  and continue using terminal as before.

Comment: Be aware that `nohup` creates a `nohup.out` file in current directory.

Comment: Yup, i know. That doesn't have any disadvantage, does it ?

Comment: Nothing beyond littering the filesystem if you use it regularly from various directories.  I mainly felt it's worth mentioning to avoid surprises.  But it tells the users it writes there, so won't really be surprising.