# How to keep application running after closing the terminal?

Tags: command-line

I am new to Ubuntu. I have used Sublime Text. I have realized that after I open Sublime Text from the Terminal, if I close the terminal the application  keeps running. The same isn't true for other applications like `geany`.

After I open the application from terminal, when I close the terminal the application also closes. I have tried `&exit` like `geany &exit`. But this isn't what I am looking for.

How can I keep `geany` running even after I close it?

Comment: You can see here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-close-a-terminal-without-killing-the-command-running-in-it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run an application with arguments from the command line without losing the terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/331451/how-do-i-run-an-application-with-arguments-from-the-command-line-without-losing)

Comment: nohup geany & disown works for me best

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**EDIT:** This may only work for certain types of terminals.  It is best to run one more command of `disown` after starting your commands like below so the applications are disassociated with the terminal window.

---

From a terminal window, type in

```
nohup geany > /dev/null
disown
```

or

```
nohup geany >/dev/null &
disown
```

`nohup` allows the application to be ran and immune to hangups, so closing the terminal window would have no effect on the application being run.  Adding the `>/dev/null` to the command prevents the creation of a `nohup.out` in each directory the application is being run from.

From the man page:

```
NAME
       nohup - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty

SYNOPSIS
       nohup COMMAND [ARG]...
       nohup OPTION
```

And

```
$ disown --help
disown: disown [-h] [-ar] [jobspec ... | pid ...]
    Remove jobs from current shell.
    
    Removes each JOBSPEC argument from the table of active jobs.  Without
    any JOBSPECs, the shell uses its notion of the current job.
    
    Options:
      -a    remove all jobs if JOBSPEC is not supplied
      -h    mark each JOBSPEC so that SIGHUP is not sent to the job if the
            shell receives a SIGHUP
      -r    remove only running jobs
    
    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless an invalid option or JOBSPEC is given.
```

Comment: @eddard.stark You're very welcome!  =)

Comment: Maybe `nohup geany > /dev/null` or `nohup geany > /dev/null &`, to prevent the creation of a `nohup.out` file in the current working directory each time the command is run

Comment: No problem, upvoted already (by the way in general feel free to not even bother crediting me in the post for such a little enhancement!)

Comment: @kos OK, I removed it.  But thanks again for the reminder.  There are times that I forget some of the simple things to stop the log output creation.  I really look forward to good suggestions from others.  =)

Comment: Often the run output is helpful/important for monitoring status or keeping track of what was done.  It this case you would want to use something like `nohup run1_cmd.sh > run1.out `.

Answer (score 13):

As an alternative to `nohup` you could use the shell builtin `disown`. `disown` removes jobs from the job list, and when the shell exists, `SIGHUP` is not sent to that process.

```
geany &
disown
exit
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `exec geany & exit` (note the exec and ampersand) if you do not need root and `pkexec geany & exit` if you need root privileges.

Comment: Definitely works with `exec nautilus-desktop & exit` :)